# nested mapping not working during test

Tags: solidity, testing, mocha, modifiers, custom-errors

I have a function that have a modifier that it must be the owner before it can cancel the order and I'm using the nested mapping that i've created for this struct as below

```
//mapping
mapping(bytes32 => mapping(uint256 => Order)) private s_orders;
mapping(bytes32 => mapping(uint256 => bool)) public s_orderCancelled;
//struct
struct Order {
        uint256 id;
        address trader;
        Status status;
        bytes32 ticker;
        uint256 amount;
        uint256 filled;
        uint256 price;
        uint256 date;
    }
//function
function cancelOrder(bytes32 _ticker, uint256 _id) external {
        Order storage orders = s_orders[_ticker][_id];

        if (address(orders.trader) != msg.sender) revert Exchange__NotOwner();
        if (orders.id == _id) revert Exchange__InvalidId();

        s_orderCancelled[_ticker][_id] = true;
    }
```

And I'm getting an error reverted with custom error 'Exchange__NotOwner() with my test script below:

```
 beforeEach(async () => {
          await dex.connect(trader1).depositToken(DAI, amount);

          transaction = await dex
            .connect(trader1)
            .createLimitOrder(REP, tradeAmount, price1, Status.BUY);
          result = await transaction.wait();

          transaction = await dex.connect(trader1).cancelOrder(REP, 1);
          result = await transaction.wait();

          await dex.connect(trader2).depositToken(REP, amount);

          transaction = await dex
            .connect(trader2)
            .createMarketOrder(REP, tradeAmount, Status.SELL);
          result = await transaction.wait();

          transaction = await dex.connect(trader2).cancelOrder(REP, 2);
          result = await transaction.wait();
        });

        it("updates cancelled orders", async () => {
          expect(await dex.s_orderCancelled(REP, 1)).to.equal(true);
          expect(await dex.s_orderCancelled(REP, 2)).to.equal(true);
        });
      });
```

not sure which syntax is wrong here

Answer (score 0):

you get Exchange__NotOwner() because you did not send your transaction from a specific address, for example, here I send the transition with account[1]:

```
sampleTranaction = await this.sampleContract.myFunc(
arg1,
arg2,
{ from: account[1] }
```

attention please before this you must set address for your account[1] as like your contract msg.sender.

Comment: I've added the from syntax like this transaction = await dex
            .connect(trader1)
            .createLimitOrder(REP, tradeAmount, price1, Status.BUY, {
              from: trader1,
            });. but its giving me invalid address or ENS name

Comment: are you sure about declaring the true address before usage?

Comment: I've declared it like this  account = await ethers.getSigners(); trader1 = account[1]; but it still giving me the same revert error transaction = await dex .connect(trader1) .createLimitOrder(REP, tradeAmount, price1, Status.BUY, { from: trader1.address });